# Implementation of Polygon class

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that contains three classes: They are `point`, `line` and `polygon`. I have written the first two, but I am having trouble with the last one.

This class has to have two constructors, one of them builds an object with a point (tip of polygon) and another one builds it with a line. These functions have to be as follows:

`polygon(point** arr,int size)` and `polygon(line** arr,int size)`.

I don't know why `point` and `line` are pointer to pointer? What are the attributes of the `polygon` class and how can I write `polygon`'s constructor?

```
class point
{
private:
    int first;
    int second;
public:
    point(void);
    point (int x,int y);
    point (const point& other);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int distance(point* other);//distance of two point
    line* Line(point*);//build a line with two point
    polygon* triangle(point*,point*);//build a triangle with three point
    ~point(void);
};
point::point(void)
{
    first=0;
    second=0;
}
point::point (int x,int y)
    {
        first=x;
        second=y;
    }
point::point(const point& other)
{
    first=other.first;
    second=other.second;
}
int point::gha(int a)
{
    if(a>=0)
        return a;
    else
        return -a;
}
int point::pow(int a)
{
    return a*a;
}
int point::getX(){return first;}
int point::getY(){return second;}
int point::distance(point* other)
{
    int d= sqrt((pow(first-other->first))+(pow(second-other->second)));
    return d;
}
line* point::Line(point* other)
{
    line l(this,other);
        return &l;
}
polygon* point::triangle(point*,point*){
}

point::~point(void)
{
}
////////////////////////////
class line
{
private:
    int m;
    int c;
public:
    line(void);
    line(point*,point*);
    line(int ,point*);
    bool isParallel(line*);
    bool isPrependicular(line*);
    point* intersection(line*);
    line* parallel(point*);
    polygon* triangle(line*,line*);
    ~line(void);
};
line::line(void)
{
    m=1;
    c=0;
}
line::line(point* a,point* b)
{
    m=((a->getY())-b->getY())/(a->getX()-b->getX());
    c=a->getY()-(m*(a->getX()));
}
line::line(int dip,point* a)
{
    m=dip;
    c=a->getY()-(dip*(a->getX()));
}
bool line:: isParallel(line* other)
{
    if(m==other->m)
     return true;
    else
    return false;
}
bool line::isPrependicular(line* other)
{
    if((m*other->m)==1 || (m*other->m)==-1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
point* line::intersection(line* other)
{
    int x=(other->c-c)/(m-other->m);
    int y=(m*x)+c;
    point p (x,y);
        return &p;
}
line* line::parallel(point* other)
{
    line l(m,other);
    return &l;
}
line::~line(void)
{
}
///////////////////////////////////
class polygon
{
private:
    int count;
    point* tip;
    line* l;
public:
    polygon(void);
    polygon(point** arr,int size);
    polygon(line** arr,int size);
    bool isTriangle();
    bool isSquare();
    ~polygon(void);
};
```

Comment: Try passing the `point` class by `const` reference, such as in the `distance` method. Prefer passing by constant reference over pointers whenever possible.

Comment: pointer to pointer is a way to modify the pointer variable that is passed to the function.  That is, it means that it points to a pointer.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` for the constructor parameters?

Comment: if possible,say me exactly how i write polygon constructor of polygon.if point* tip and line* l are attribute of polygon class.

Comment: you should learn more about C++ before doing more advanced things: You should learn about containers, about object members initialization, etc. Also to not mix C with C++ (Naked pointers, void is not necessary in C++ to denote non-parameters functions, just use (), etc).

Comment: Don't return pointers/references to local variables, don't use pointers as paramameters, use (const) references or pass by value, etc. As you can see, **your code has a lot of mistakes** (Important mistakes). Go and read a good C++ book (Refer to the C++ book list on the C++FAQ)